# Disabling AWS X-ray in FastAPI Lambda application

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, python-asyncio, fastapi, aws-xray

We have a Lambda application written in FastAPI and we had enabled X-ray for it. However, we decided to move to Datadog and now we don't need X-ray anymore. However, we're finding it hard to actually disable X-ray from recording traces.

These are the approaches we've tried:

1. `global_sdk_config.set_sdk_enabled(False)` (Disabling through the SDKConfig module)
2. `AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED=false` (Disabling through the environment variable)
3. Not even calling the functions to [start/end segments](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python#trace-aws-lambda-functions)
4. Adding another env var according to the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/blob/80fe6b22a66be175e862845798eba3de946dfc8c/aws_xray_sdk/sdk_config.py#L29) - `AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED` - and setting it to `false`

But none of them worked. We are still getting the traces on the AWS X-ray console.

We also found an [open issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/issues/170) with the `aws-xray-sdk-python` library that says that it's currently may not even be possible to disable X-ray for `async`. And we use `async` extensively since we have FastAPI.

We wanted to understand from the community if turning off X-ray is indeed impossible for `async` flow (because the Github issue is still open). We have even considered reaching out to AWS technical support, but wanted to understand from the StackOverflow community first.

Comment: Have you disabled the active tracing on your lambda function? If you're still getting traces after disabling it, is there an upstream service invoking this lambda function with `Sample=1` in it's trace header?

Comment: @PrashantSrivastava - Yes, I disabled active tracing using CFTs, but I don't believe there's any upstream service calling the Lambda function. Our front end calls the API gateway endpoint, and the request is routed to our Lambda function, and neither the front end nor the API gateway endpoint send any `Sample=1` headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

Xray tracing is separately configured for API Gateways as well. I had to turn that off, along with tracing for functions, in order to completely remove Xray from our architecture.